# We're using firebase with react-native and firebase is using crashlytics(I'm guessing). we run into these errors

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-ios, crashlytics

I've been trying to figure this out and have tried several approaches, so this is my last resort. I can try maybe deleting crashlytics, but I don't know how to go about that. Does anyone have any suggestions. I also tried adding in crashlytics on Podfile, but that didn't work either.

This only happens when i run command 'npx react-native run-ios'.
The command 'npx react-native start' runs fine

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CLSMachOFormatVersion", referenced from:
      _CLSBinaryImageRecordMainExecutable in Crashlytics(CLSBinaryImage.o)
  "_CLSMachOGetEncrypted", referenced from:
      ___CLSBinaryImageFillInImageDetails_block_invoke in Crashlytics(CLSBinaryImage.o)
  "_CLSMachOGetLinkedSDKVersion", referenced from:
      ___CLSBinaryImageFillInImageDetails_block_invoke in Crashlytics(CLSBinaryImage.o)
  "_CLSMachOGetMinimumOSVersion", referenced from:
      ___CLSBinaryImageFillInImageDetails_block_invoke in Crashlytics(CLSBinaryImage.o)
  "_CLSMachOGetUUID", referenced from:
      ___CLSBinaryImageFillInImageDetails_block_invoke in Crashlytics(CLSBinaryImage.o)
  "_CLSMachOSliceEnumerateLoadCommands", referenced from:
      _CLSBinaryImageFillInImageDetails in Crashlytics(CLSBinaryImage.o)
  "_CLSMachOSliceGetArchitectureName", referenced from:
      _CLSBinaryImageRecordMainExecutable in Crashlytics(CLSBinaryImage.o)
  "_CLSMachOSliceGetCurrent", referenced from:
      _CLSBinaryImageRecordMainExecutable in Crashlytics(CLSBinaryImage.o)
  "_CLSMachOSliceGetExecutablePath", referenced from:
      ___CLSBinaryImageChanged_block_invoke in Crashlytics(CLSBinaryImage.o)
  "_CLSMachOSliceIs64Bit", referenced from:
      _CLSBinaryImageMachOSliceInitSectionByName in Crashlytics(CLSBinaryImage.o)
  "_CLSMachOSliceWithHeader", referenced from:
      _CLSBinaryImageFindImageForUUID in Crashlytics(CLSBinaryImage.o)
      _CLSBinaryImageChanged in Crashlytics(CLSBinaryImage.o)
  "_FABApplicationGetBundleIdentifier", referenced from:
      -[CLSFileManager pathNamespace] in Crashlytics(CLSFileManager.o)
      -[CLSBetaController appBundleIdentifier] in Crashlytics(CLSBetaController.o)
      -[CLSCrashReportingController bundleIdentifier] in Crashlytics(CLSCrashReportingController.o)
      -[ANSMetadata initWithFabric:betaToken:] in Crashlytics(ANSMetadata.o)
      +[ANSAnswersController rootDirectory] in Crashlytics(ANSAnswersController.o)
      ___CLSContextInitialize_block_invoke.26 in Crashlytics(CLSContext.o)
  "_FABApplicationGetBundleVersion", referenced from:
      -[CLSBetaController appBuildVersion] in Crashlytics(CLSBetaController.o)
      -[ANSMetadata initWithFabric:betaToken:] in Crashlytics(ANSMetadata.o)
      ___CLSContextInitialize_block_invoke.26 in Crashlytics(CLSContext.o)
  "_FABApplicationGetName", referenced from:
      -[CLSBetaUpdate promptMessage] in Crashlytics(CLSBetaUpdate.o)
  "_FABApplicationGetShortBundleVersion", referenced from:
      -[CLSBetaController appDisplayVersion] in Crashlytics(CLSBetaController.o)
      -[ANSMetadata initWithFabric:betaToken:] in Crashlytics(ANSMetadata.o)
      ___CLSContextInitialize_block_invoke.26 in Crashlytics(CLSContext.o)
  "_FABApplicationInstallationSource", referenced from:
      +[CLSBetaController isBetaSupported] in Crashlytics(CLSBetaController.o)
      -[CLSBetaController appInstallationSource] in Crashlytics(CLSBetaController.o)
  "_FABBuiltinCertificates", referenced from:
      +[CLSBetaController pinnnedCertificates] in Crashlytics(CLSBetaController.o)
      +[CLSNetworkClient pinner] in Crashlytics(CLSNetworkClient.o)
      -[ANSNetworkRetryHandler init] in Crashlytics(ANSNetworkRetryHandler.o)
  "_FABEnumerateByteRangesOfNSDataUsingBlock", referenced from:
      -[CLSPackageReportOperation compressData:toPath:] in Crashlytics(CLSPackageReportOperation.o)
  "_FABGenerateUUID", referenced from:
      -[ANSEvent init] in Crashlytics(ANSEvent.o)
      -[ANSAnswersController generateNewLogPath] in Crashlytics(ANSAnswersController.o)
  "_FABHostGetOSVersion", referenced from:
      _CLSHostGetNormalizedOSVersion in Crashlytics(CLSHost.o)
  "_FABHostModelInfo", referenced from:
      ___20-[Crashlytics start]_block_invoke in Crashlytics(Crashlytics.o)
      -[ANSMetadata initWithFabric:betaToken:] in Crashlytics(ANSMetadata.o)
      _CLSHostRecord in Crashlytics(CLSHost.o)
  "_FABHostOSBuildVersion", referenced from:
      ___20-[Crashlytics start]_block_invoke in Crashlytics(Crashlytics.o)
      -[ANSMetadata initWithFabric:betaToken:] in Crashlytics(ANSMetadata.o)
      _CLSHostRecord in Crashlytics(CLSHost.o)
  "_FABHostOSDisplayVersion", referenced from:
      ___20-[Crashlytics start]_block_invoke in Crashlytics(Crashlytics.o)
      -[ANSMetadata initWithFabric:betaToken:] in Crashlytics(ANSMetadata.o)
      _CLSHostRecord in Crashlytics(CLSHost.o)
  "_FABNetworkErrorDomain", referenced from:
      -[ANSNetworkRetryHandler errorWithCode:forIdentifier:request:handlerError:] in Crashlytics(ANSNetworkRetryHandler.o)
      -[ANSUploader errorWithCode:userInfo:] in Crashlytics(ANSUploader.o)
  "_FABNetworkMaximumRetryCount", referenced from:
      ___51-[CLSBetaController loadUpdateWithCompletionBlock:]_block_invoke in Crashlytics(CLSBetaController.o)
  "_FABSettingsAvailableNotification", referenced from:
      -[CLSBetaController start] in Crashlytics(CLSBetaController.o)
      -[CLSCrashReportingController startCrashReporterWithAPIKey:betaToken:profilingMark:report:] in Crashlytics(CLSCrashReportingController.o)
      -[CLSCrashReportingController fabricSettingsDownloaded:] in Crashlytics(CLSCrashReportingController.o)
      -[ANSAnswersController initWithBetaToken:rootDirectory:] in Crashlytics(ANSAnswersController.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLSURLSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Crashlytics(CLSNetworkClient.o)
      objc-class-ref in Crashlytics(ANSUploader.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLSURLSessionConfiguration", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Crashlytics(CLSNetworkClient.o)
      objc-class-ref in Crashlytics(ANSUploader.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FABCertificatePinner", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Crashlytics(CLSNetworkClient.o)
      objc-class-ref in Crashlytics(ANSNetworkRetryHandler.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FABMultipartMimeStreamEncoder", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Crashlytics(CLSPackageReportOperation.o)
      objc-class-ref in Crashlytics(CLSReportsController.o)
      objc-class-ref in Crashlytics(ANSPackageLogOperation.o)
      objc-class-ref in Crashlytics(ANSAnswersController.o)
      objc-class-ref in Crashlytics(ANSUploadOperation.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FABNetworkClient", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Crashlytics(CLSBetaController.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FABNetworkResponseHandler", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Crashlytics(CLSNetworkClient.o)
      objc-class-ref in Crashlytics(ANSNetworkRetryHandler.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FABURLBuilder", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Crashlytics(CLSBetaController.o)
      objc-class-ref in Crashlytics(CLSReportsController.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Fabric", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Crashlytics(Crashlytics.o)
      objc-class-ref in Crashlytics(CLSBetaController.o)
      objc-class-ref in Crashlytics(CLSCrashReportingController.o)
      objc-class-ref in Crashlytics(CLSReportsController.o)
      objc-class-ref in Crashlytics(CLSNetworkClient.o)
      objc-class-ref in Crashlytics(Answers.o)
      objc-class-ref in Crashlytics(CLSFCRAnalytics.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld /Users/aashmangupta/Desktop/CS/CS495/pantryCLI/LogicalPantry/ios/build/LogicalPantry/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/LogicalPantry.app/LogicalPantry normal x86_64
(1 failure)
```

Comment: So if anyone is wondering, I updated to latest version of react and ran npm install again, and it worked :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution aashman!